# Cyper - odd error when creating relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've got the following query, which responds with the very cryptic error message of

```
"Invalid input 'H': expected 'i/I' (line 2, column 2)"
```

Here's the query:

```
CREATE UNIQUE (c:AccountCharge)-[:ACCOUNT_CHARGED]->(a:Account)
WHERE (a.ID = "a7f7def6-8f2b-4b21-bfac-dab2f6e6eaae")
AND (c.ID = "666b1865-e29d-455b-abb0-50d679952543")
```

Both the nodes exist, and I can't see where there's a break anywhere, but Neo4J does not like it at all.

The query's being created by C# Neo4JClient, but even retyping it manually I still get the same error, so it's not a hidden character or anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WHERE can only be used with the MATCH clause.

The expected **I** is because for cypher the possible clause after a CREATE is a **WITH** clause, so the second letter is a I instead of a H.

You should then first MATCH the two nodes and create the unique relationship afterwards

Comment: Derp - totally fixed it, thank you for the quick response!